# Qt for Symbian S60 - "Feature not supported"

Tags: qt, symbian, s60, sis

I'm developing an application with Qt for the Symbian platform, and I ran into a problem when testing the app on an S60 phone, Nokia E90.

The application compiles just fine, but when I'm installing the sis-file the phone notifies me that a "Feature is not supported".

Here's a list of capabilities that I'm using:

```
LocalServices ReadUserData WriteUserData NetworkServices 
UserEnvironment Location ReadDeviceData NetworkControl
```

I'm also using Qt Mobility:

```
systeminfo bearer location
```

The app installs just fine on Symbian^3, but not on S60. What could be the problem?

Best regards

Comment: I guess you've installed QtMobility on the S60 3rd FP1 device before you try installing your sis?

Comment: I have installed every sis-file that came with the Qt SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the question is which version of QtSDK do you use. QtSDK 1.1 does not support S60 anymore. Only Symbian^1 (5th generation) and Symbian^3 are supported by QtSDK 1.1 .

S60 devices are supported only by the QtSDK 1.0.

Best Regards

Comment: I'm using Qt SDK 1.1, but why are some applications working just fine on S60, and others not? Is it Qt Mobility that is causing the trouble?

Comment: According to the Qt Mobility documentation at http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.1/index.html#platform-compatibility the S60 platform is fully supported excluding the document gallery and feedback modules.